# Java 8 multiple level flatMap best implementation

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I have this two code examples:

Code A:

```
Stream<String> aStream = firstLevelList.stream()
                            .flatMap(firstLevelElement -> firstLevelElement.getSecondLevelList().stream()
                                .flatMap(secondLevelElement -> secondLevelElement.getThirdLevelList().stream()
                                    .map(thirdLevelElement -> thirdLevelElement.toString())));
```

Code B:

```
Stream<String> aStream = firstLevelList.stream()
                            .flatMap(firstLevelElement -> firstLevelElement.getSecondLevelList().stream())
                            .flatMap(secondLevelElement -> secondLevelElement.getThirdLevelList().stream())
                            .map(thirdLevelElement -> thirdLevelElement.toString());
```

Both have exactly the same result, which is the best implementation? Why?

Comment: if you can show what are you trying to archive, chances are there may be better approaches

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Choose whichever you feel reads better.

Comment: There is no technical difference, but obviously, the second, avoiding the deep nesting, increases the readability, as you don’t have to guess the brace pairing of the ending `))));` nor are you inclined to raise the indentation in each line…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

The following reads nicely and feels more common:

```
firstLevelList.stream()
        .flatMap(firstLevelElement -> firstLevelElement.getSecondLevelList().stream())
        .flatMap(secondLevelElement -> secondLevelElement.getThirdLevelList().stream())
        .map(Object::toString);
```

It avoids the nesting as @Holger pointed out, which is important for the reader.

**Option 2**

Alternatively, we could use a different indentation for the nesting if it's not at odds with the rest of the code base style:

```
firstLevelList.stream().flatMap(
        firstLevelElement -> firstLevelElement.getSecondLevelList().stream().flatMap(
                secondLevelElement -> secondLevelElement.getThirdLevelList().stream().map(Object::toString)
        )
);
```

**Option 3**

If it still feels too cryptic, we could extract variables or methods to name the different streams:

```
firstLevelList.stream().flatMap(
        firstLevelElement -> firstLevelElement.getSecondLevelList().stream().flatMap(
                secondLevelElement -> getThirdLevelStream(secondLevelElement)
        )
);

Stream<String> getThirdLevelStream(SecondLevelElement secondLevelElement) {
    return secondLevelElement.getThirdLevelList().stream().map(Object::toString);
}
```

**Option 4**

We can move these methods to the element classes respecting now the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter):

```
firstLevelList.stream().flatMap(FirstLevelElement::getSecondLevelStream);

class FirstLevelElement {

    Stream<String> getSecondLevelStream() {
        return this.getSecondLevelList().stream().flatMap(SecondLevelElement::getThirdLevelStream);
    }

    Collection<SecondLevelElement> getSecondLevelList() {...}
}

class SecondLevelElement {

    Stream<String> getThirdLevelStream() {
        return this.getThirdLevelList().stream().map(Object::toString);
    }

    Collection<ThirdLevelElement> getThirdLevelList() {...}
}
```

This will add some value if the stream methods are reused somewhere else in the code.

**Conclusion**

Different arguments can be made about which of these options is better. In general, they are all perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer method references for neatness:

```
Stream<String> aStream = firstLevelList.stream()
    .map(FirstLevelElement::getSecondLevelList)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .map(SecondLevelElement::getThirdLevelList)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .map(Object::toString);
```